# Bootstrap col-xs-push-12 col-xs-pull-12

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to now where I made mistake? It doesn't happen:

```
5      7
```

to

```
7
5
```

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12">5</div>
<div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12">7</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pgysLzr4/18/ here is demo. It is going out of screen

Comment: looks fine to me? Please explain the situation carefully

Comment: You will also need to make sure you include Bootstrap CSS....

Comment: Try expanding the jsfiddle preview so its width exceeds 1000px.

Comment: what must I do for this?

Comment: _“what must I do for this?”_ - please go read [ask] first of all. And then use your _words_ to describe what actual problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: The pull/push classes are meant to offset column positions horizontally (like this, http://jsfiddle.net/pgysLzr4/20/) - they are not meant to work on “full-width” columns though. Either change the order of the elements (so that 7 first, 5 second is the “default” order, and then use pull/push to get them ordered differently in the “big screen” view) - or use a different technique altogether (like flexbox order.)